# Using tuples as multiple assignings for different objects

Tags: c#, tuples

For example, I have several objects in the same context (code block):

```
Button button;
public string FormCaption { get; set; }
public List<int> myValues { get; set; }
```

And I have a method that returns vaues for all these objects

```
(string ButtonName, string FormCaption, List<int> SomeValues) MyCoolMethod() {...}
```

Don't ask me why - that is just an example. If I assign aforementioned objects like this below, am I actually using a tuple as the left operand, or is it just a syntactic sugar for assigning?

```
(button.Name, FormCaption, myValues) = MyCoolMethod();
```

What disadvantages do you see to make assignings like this instead of making it so:

```
var result = MyCoolMethod();
button.Name = result.ButtonName;
FormCaption = result.FormCaption;
myValues  = result.SomeValues;
```

? I mean not only readability (perhaps not in this example, but in some real case it can be more readable and suitable), but in terms of performance and memory consumption.

Comment: look at the generated IL - I'm guessing its the same or pretty darn close

Comment: Your method `MyCoolMethod` returns a tuple that is deconstructed and its values assigned to your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I assign aforementioned objects like this below, am I actually using a tuple as the left operand, or is it just a syntactic sugar for assigning?

Well, according to the [draft PR that will standardize deconstructing assignment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/pull/664) it *is* a "tuple expression" - but that doesn't mean it creates a tuple value. (Even if it did, it would be a `ValueTuple<,,>` so wouldn't require any heap allocation.)

In fact, the compiler does significant work not only to avoid creating `ValueTuple` objects when they're not needed - e.g. in an assignment of `(this.x, this.y, this.z) = (x, y, z)` in a constructor - but it avoids even requiring the `ValueTuple` *type* to be available if it can avoid it.